# ElasticSearch heap usage

Tags: memory, elasticsearch, out-of-memory, heap-memory

A 3 nodes cluster with 20gb heap given to each node.

Checked stats and memory usage stands at 97-99%.
Checked fielddata stats and it shows 15gb total, which I guess makes it 5gb for each node - which is reasonable, given that each node has 20gb, right?

So is there a way to check what's using the rest of the heap?

The cluster was mostly indexing new data and almost no searches were running.
All three nodes are running on the same hardware machine.
Each node has ~1tb of indexed data.
Disks are SSD.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @wogsland which code?

Comment: I would start looking at `doc_values` ;-):https://www.elastic.co/blog/disk-based-field-data-a-k-a-doc-values 97-99% heap usage is like your node is about to die in the next second.

Comment: Stefan, we are already using doc values for some of the fields. In my question I noted that field data is taking only quarter of the heap, so I'm not sure doc values would solve the current problem.

Comment: Es version is 1.5.2 btw